# Selenium click causes page to pop up error landing page

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, selenium

Given click on element by xpath:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Or with js:

```
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath))
```

On the page that I'm testing, if the click is done with either option, an error landing page is displayed, but if I put a timeout of 20 seconds and I manually click on the botton the page displays everything with no problem, no error page pops up.

Did anybody encountered this sort of issue ever ?

Comment: What if you add a sleep before the click like, `time.sleep(20)`

Comment: Did that, just so I can click on it myself, and left it to run with it also, it seems that chrome is doing some weird stuff, even tho i cleared cache and everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using the following function:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def test_for_clickability(driver, by_type, by_value, wait_time=0):
    try:
        return WebDriverWait(driver, wait_time).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((by_type, by_value))), True
    except TimeoutException:
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.visibility_of((by_type, by_value))), FALSE
        except Exception:
            return (None, False)
```

For example:

```
element, clickable = test_for_clickability(driver, By.XPATH, xpath, wait_time=20)
```

The above will wait up to 20 seconds to try to find the element by its XPATH. If it cannot find it, the `element` value will be returned as `None`. If not `None`, `clickable` will be `True` if the element will respond to the `element.click()` method call. Otherwise, you should try using a `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)` call.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly assume that your element is not clickable yet, because it's not fully loaded at the point the program is trying to click it. Therefore the problem doesn't happen if you wait 20 seconds. I would recommend you to look at this: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

You can use a method to wait for your element to fully load before clicking it.

Just some code for illustration:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("your.web.url")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "yourXPATH"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```